# Type Mismatch when pasting multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I am trying to paste a time worked database into an excel file which will auto-calculate how long each job took and the total amount of hours worked.  When I copy/paste one cell at a time, everything works fine.  When I try copying 2 or more cells, I get a "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch" error on:

`Tlen = Len(Target)`

Here is a screen capture video of what I am working with: https://youtu.be/Qhd37U3SLQU

What I ultimately am trying to do is at 1:05 of the video.
Essentially, I am trying to paste a block of info from a database into my excel file and filter out anything that is not time. Column D calculates the duration between start and stop time and E2 would have the sum of column D.

My current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not IsNumeric(Target) Then
    'do nothing
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a2:c900" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Columns.Count)) Is Nothing Then
    Tlen = Len(Target)
    Targval = Target.Value

If Tlen = 1 Then
        TimeV = TimeValue("00:" & Target)


ElseIf Tlen = 2 And Targval < 60 Then
    TimeV = TimeValue("00:" & Target)
ElseIf Tlen = 2 And 60 <= Targval Then
    'do nothing


        ElseIf Tlen = 3 And Targval >= 160 And Targval <= 199 Or Targval >= 260 And Targval <= 299 Or Targval >= 360 And Targval <= 399 Or Targval >= 460 And Targval <= 499 Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Tlen = 3 And Targval >= 560 And Targval <= 599 Or Targval >= 660 And Targval <= 699 Or Targval >= 760 And Targval <= 799 Or Targval >= 860 And Targval <= 899 Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Tlen = 3 And Targval >= 960 And Targval <= 999 Then
            'do nothing
ElseIf Tlen = 3 Then
    TimeV = TimeValue(Left(Target, 1) & ":" & Right(Target, 2))


        ElseIf Tlen = 4 And Targval >= 1060 And Targval <= 1099 Or Targval >= 1160 And Targval <= 1199 Or Targval >= 1260 And Targval <= 1299 Or Targval >= 1360 And Targval <= 1399 Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Tlen = 4 And Targval >= 1460 And Targval <= 1499 Or Targval >= 1560 And Targval <= 1599 Or Targval >= 1660 And Targval <= 1699 Or Targval >= 1760 And Targval <= 1799 Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Tlen = 4 And Targval >= 1860 And Targval <= 1899 Or Targval >= 1960 And Targval <= 1999 Or Targval >= 2060 And Targval <= 2099 Or Targval >= 2160 And Targval <= 2199 Then
            'do nothing
        ElseIf Tlen = 4 And Targval >= 2260 And Targval <= 2299 Or Targval >= 2360 And Targval <= 2399 Then
            'do nothing
ElseIf Tlen = 4 And Targval < 2400 Then
    TimeV = TimeValue(Left(Target, 2) & ":" & Right(Target, 2))
        ElseIf Tlen >= 4 And Targval >= 2400 Then
            'do nothing

End If

Target.NumberFormat = "HHMM"

Application.EnableEvents = False
Target = TimeV
Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't you `Exit Sub` if target is not numeric? That code just continues on regardless of what target is.

Comment: Do you want process each cell in target or skip all processing?

Comment: When you check the Intersect of Target and your range of interest, you should then just work on the return value from intersect, in case a multi-cell Target has some cells outside of the range you're checking for.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that Intersect is pretty henky.

Comment: updated my post with a video of my current code and what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code is a bit confusing when supplied without sample data and expected results but I believe this is what you are trying to do.

> <sub>Take a 1 to 4 digit number from Base 10 and convert it to time in HHMM format.</sub>

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a:c"), Me.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("a:c"), Me.UsedRange)
            If IsNumeric(t) And LCase(t.NumberFormat) <> "hhmm" And LCase(t.NumberFormat <> "[hh]mm") Then
                t.NumberFormat = "[hh]mm"
                t = TimeSerial(Int(t.Value / 100), (t.Value Mod 100), 0)
                'alternate
                't = TimeSerial(Int(val(t.text) / 100), (val(t.text) Mod 100), 0)
                't.NumberFormat = "[hh]mm"
            End If
        Next t
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: this works almost exactly how I wanted it to except  that whenever a number is that isn't a normal time value (like 1969, 2500) is inputted, the following entries added get screwed up (typing 1900 turns it into 4569000).  I tried adding to your code to  'do nothing whenever a target.value hits > 2400 similar to what I had on my original code, but it does not fix the issue.

Comment: 1900 becomes 1900 (07:00 pm); 1969 becomes 2009 (08:09 pm or 19 hours + 69 minutes; 2500 becomes 2500 (1 day, 1 hour). I fail to see the problem. If you receive 4569000 then you are likely inputting a datetime and not a time. Please supply sample data and expected results, noting any limitations that may be obvious to you but not to me.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I copied and pasted your original code into VBA.  
The symptoms I was describing on your initial answer is now more unpredictable with the edit.
What would occur with the initial code is if I were to input "1597" into cell A1, It would turn into "1537" (3:37pm).  If I were then to input "1900" into A2, or any other cell in the range, the cell would turn into "4560000."  I would have to re-open a new excel sheet and re-paste the code for that to stop happening.

Comment: with your most recent edit, I have posted a screen recording to show what exactly what is happening:
https://youtu.be/50_Hxw_4WiM

Comment: OK, I get it. The system thinks you are typing in a date so it converts the 1900 to something like 1/1/1900 before attempting to process into time.. Format the column as number and you should be good to go. Oddly, my system did not attempt the same conversion when the column is formatted as General.